# How to store user input data in console log on form submit from child to parent component?

Tags: reactjs, form-submit

I have my child components within my parent component and I would like to be able to console log what data a user has submitted. However, being new to react I am not sure how I should do this?. Would love some help!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import PageOne from './Components/PageOne';
import PageTwo from './Components/PageTwo';
import PageThree from './Components/PageThree';
import PageFour from './Components/PageFour';
import PageFive from './Components/PageFive';
import PageSix from './Components/PageSix';
import PageSeven from './Components/PageSeven';
import { Input, Dropdown, TextArea, Form, Button, Header } from 'semantic- 
ui-react'


class App extends Component {
  render() {
     return (
      <div className="App">
         <PageOne />
         <PageTwo />
         <PageThree />
         <PageFour />
         <PageFive />
         <PageSix />

         <Button>
            Submit Form
         </Button>

         <br/>
         <br/>

     </div>

    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: hi tom, could you provide a little more info? what exactly would you like to log? Is there some form component that will have data, and on button click you would like to console.log the contents of the form?

Comment: Hi Julian, thats exactly it, Within my components (pageome, two, three etc) I have a fields for the users to fill out. I would like to log the data the user has submitted. I want to essentially be able to submit a form to the console.log and view what is being stored from the parent component. Does this make sense?

Comment: @TomHunt. I've provided a breakdown of how to accomplish what you're looking for below. Let me know if you have any questions. And welcome to StackOverFlow!

Answer (score 0):

We can pass a callback through the `Parent` component as props to `Child` and invoke it after handling the form submission.

You cant really "store" it in the console, What are you trying to do exactly ?

Do you want to save the user submitted data to use later in a part of your App? if so you could pass a call back to set the state in your `Parent` component with the data submitted, this way you can share the data with other `Child` components through the `Parent` `state`

The important thing to understand here is that we pass callbacks as props to `Child` components when we need to pass data to `Parent` components and save it to our `state` this way our `Parent` can share the state with the rest of our `App`.

```
function Parent() {
  const logAfterSubmit = data => {
    console.log("user submitted data", data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child logAfterSubmit={logAfterSubmit} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ logAfterSubmit }) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do something with the data

    // call our function from parent with the data
    logAfterSubmit(input);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5xyz5nr29k)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. React is an amazing tool for developing websites. Unique to React is a concept called "state" which is essentially what you're looking for. "State" is React's ability to keep track of data and use it accordingly. In your case, you want to record what a user submits in your child component.

Let's consider the following code:

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    //define state here which is typically an empty object
    state = {
       text: ""
    }

   //this is an event handler we have set up to take the data from state
  handleOnSubmit = () => {
      event.prevent.default() //stops page from refreshing
      console.log(this.state.text)
  }

 //event handler that is triggered every time a user makes a change to the input
  handleOnChange = (event) => {
      //unique method in React that lets you update the component state
      this.setState({
         text: event.target.value
      })
  }

   //all class-based components are called with render
   render(){
     return(
        //we can pass down event handlers/functions we've defined into child components.
        <Child handleOnChange={this.handleOnChange} handleOnSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}/>
     )
   }

}
```

Now for our Child Component

```
//this is known as a stateless-functional component. no need to keep track of state.
const Child = (props) => {
   return(
     <form onSubmit={props.handleOnSubmit}>
        //onChange is a unique-event listener that gets called anytime characters changes inside an input tag. So in this case we update our Parent's state every time we type.
        <input onChange={props.handleOnChange} name="text" />
     </form>
   )
}
```

So a high-level summary of this. We set up a parent-component and defined functions inside of it that will help keep track of "state" or data. Then we pass down those functions as properties to our Child component. Our child component uses those functions and when they are called, they will update the state in our Parent component. Thus giving you a controlled-input flow, where you are constantly keeping track of data coming into your forms.